# Code printing stuff in the completely wrong order

Tags: python

````
```import random
from random import randint


pc = randint(1, 3)
playerinput = input("1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3 = Scissors")


def start():
    pc = randint(1, 3)

    if playerinput == 1:
        if pc == 2:
            print("You lose!")
        elif pc == 1:
            print("You draw!")
        else:
            print("You win!")


    elif playerinput == 2:
        if pc == 2:
            print("You draw!")
        elif pc == 3:
            print ("You lose!")
        else:
            print("You win!")

    else:
        if pc == 3:
            print("You draw!")
        elif pc == 2:
            print("You win!")
        else:
            print("You lose!")


again = input("Would you like to play again? Type 'YES' if so")
if again == "YES" or "yes" or "Yes" or "yEs" or "yeS" or "YEs" or "YeS":
    start()```
````

It prints the rock paper or scissors, then it just goes would you like to play again. if you say yes, it then prints whether you won, lost or tied. what's wrong?

Comment: Consider `if again.lower() == 'yes'`

Answer (score 1):

You call the Player-input only once, so once the Player made on decision calling `start()` will only generate a new random int. From what I understand you want to change the code into something like this, asking the player for input each time `start()` is called:
(Note that the pc before the definition is not needed aswell, since you reset it in `start()`)

```
import random
from random import randint

def start():
    pc = randint(1, 3)
    playerinput = input("1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3 = Scissors")

    if playerinput == 1:
        if pc == 2:
            print("You lose!")
        elif pc == 1:
            print("You draw!")
        else:
            print("You win!")


    elif playerinput == 2:
        if pc == 2:
            print("You draw!")
        elif pc == 3:
            print ("You lose!")
        else:
            print("You win!")

    else:
        if pc == 3:
            print("You draw!")
        elif pc == 2:
            print("You win!")
        else:
            print("You lose!")

start()

while True:
    again = input("Would you like to play again? Type 'YES' if so")
    if again == "YES" or "yes" or "Yes" or "yEs" or "yeS" or "YEs" or "YeS":
        start()
    else:
        break
```

EDIT: As stated in the comment to your question by a different user, you shuold change the if to just `if again.lower() = "yes" to be more clean. Also`import random`is not necessary if you call`from random import randint` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

That's because 'randint' randomly initialize a number from 1-3 whenever invoked.

```
randint(1, 3)
```

So, whichever number the user enters, the function reinitialize the number and prints:

either "You win!", "You lose!", or "You draw!".

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call your function after defined it.

You need to add `start()` before again.
Also if you want to play everytime the user said yes you need to had a loop

```py
import random
from random import randint


pc = randint(1, 3)
playerinput = input("1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3 = Scissors")


def start():
    pc = randint(1, 3)

    if playerinput == 1:
        if pc == 2:
            print("You lose!")
        elif pc == 1:
            print("You draw!")
        else:
            print("You win!")


    elif playerinput == 2:
        if pc == 2:
            print("You draw!")
        elif pc == 3:
            print ("You lose!")
        else:
            print("You win!")

    else:
        if pc == 3:
            print("You draw!")
        elif pc == 2:
            print("You win!")
        else:
            print("You lose!")

start()

while True:
   again = input("Would you like to play again? Type 'YES' if so")
   if again == "YES" or "yes" or "Yes" or "yEs" or "yeS" or "YEs" or "YeS":
      start()
   else:
      break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read input inside `start`.

Also, your if statement will always be `True` because
`if "yes":`
will pass.

In any case you want to do something like `again.lower() == 'yes'`

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the first input to the function `start`, remove the first `pc = randint` and then call the function below its definition.